# OAuth2 Resource Server calling Authorization Server to validate token

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I am new to OAuth2 concept but trying to setup a simple system that will consist of 2 separate microservices (no UI yet, will use REST client for test purpose):

1. Authorization Server with own database which will own User entity, credentials, all other information needed for MFA for example.
2. Resource Server with its own database, which will have a User Projection entity. I want my Resource server to drive UserManagement flow, which will save on its side non-auth user information, like address, titles, logos etc and will just call Auth Server to store auth information.

If I understood the oauth2 flow propertly i will have to:

1. call Authorization Server first with user/password to obtain access token.
2. Then using this access token i will call my Resource server.
3. Resource server should call Authorization Server to validate the token.

My question replies to step-3.
What I did is some basic configuration on Authorization Server side:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      client-id: clientId
      client-secret: very-strong-secret
      provider:
        issuer-uri: http://localhost:8080/oauth/token
```

And on Resource server side:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: http://localhost:8080/oauth/token
```

my resource server is starting on port 8081 and calling localhost on port 8080 where authorization server is running.

I was able to obtain access token, but when I am calling resource server (I assume spring makes a magic and calling auth server under the hood) i get the error:

```
Unable to resolve the Configuration with the provided Issuer of "http://localhost:8080/oauth/token"
```

How exactly should I instruct my resource server to validate the token?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple. If you don't configure the issuer uri explicitly, the default value is host:port.( In your case it's just `http://localhost:8080` )